# Apache and Node.js servers can't open socket.io because of proxy

Tags: node.js, html, apache, proxy, socket.io

We have the following setup.

An apache server which is listening on port 80 on mydomain.org and a nodejs server which is listening on port 7000 on localhost. Forthermore we have setup a proxy to the node server which is on mydomain.org/node.

We need to implement socket.io but we have the problem that the client is always trying to connect to mydomain.org/socket.io instead of mydomain.org/node/socket.io.

In Firebug we get this error log:

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   “mydomain.org/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdvhazU...

and in node.js console get this error log:

> GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdvhgCU HTTP/1.1" 404 16

How we can solve this problem?

The code of server and client side as follows:

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// Loading .html index file on client side
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});

// Loading socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Notify when client connects in console
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A client is connected!');
});

// Show in console that server listenig port 7000
server.listen(7000, function() {
    console.log("Listening port 7000");
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Node.js Socket.io Test-6</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
    header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, figure, audio, video, canvas  { display:block; }
  </style>    
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      Header
    </header>
    <nav>
      Nav
    </nav>
    <section id="content">
      <article>
        Article
      </article>
    </section>
    <aside>
      Sidebar
    </aside>
    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('mydomain.org/node/');
    </script>     
</body>
</html>
```

Proxy config:

```
ProxyPass  /node http://localhost:7000
ProxyPassReverse /node   http://localhost:7000
```

Comment: Add your proxy config - the issue is probably going to be there. It looks like the URL is getting rewritten incorrectly.

Comment: This is proxy config @Kryten 
ProxyPass  /node http://localhost:7000
ProxyPassReverse /node   http://localhost:7000

Comment: Did you ever solve this?